# ¿Es posible recuperar una respuesta eliminada en otra pregunta?

Tags: discusión, votos-de-reapertura

Bueno ocurrió algo ayer que nunca me había pasado.

Se formuló una pregunta sobre la posibilidad de conocer la IP del cliente sea usando JS o PHP.

En dicha pregunta yo compartí un script que uso para tales fines en PHP, pero al OP se le sugirió que formulase dos preguntas por separado, entre tanto la pregunta fue cerrada.

El OP, para fines de reapertura, modificó la pregunta, pidiendo sólo código JS. Mi respuesta sobraba allí, pues era de PHP, por lo tanto su destino era la eliminación, como he hecho.

Entre tanto el OP lanzó la misma pregunta, pero para PHP. Pero la nueva pregunta fue cerrada al considerarse duplicada de la primera.

El hecho es que las dos preguntas son válidas y creo que podrían existir las dos en esSO.

Actualmente la situación es la siguiente:

Pregunta para JS abierta.
Pregunta para PHP cerrada por considerarse duplicada de la anterior, pero actualmente no lo es (ya tiene varios votos de reapertura).

Mi duda es la siguiente: si la pregunta para PHP es reabierta **¿es posible recuperar mi respuesta (actualmente eliminada en la respuesta de JS), en la pregunta de PHP?**

Aquí dejo los enlaces de las dos preguntas:

- JS (cerrada y reabierta): [Obtener IP de cliente desde Javascript jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67217/29967)
- PHP (actualmente cerrada): [Obtener IP de cliente desde PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67370/29967)

  ---
- [Respuesta que quiero recuperar, pero en la otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67235/29967)

Comment: Nunca había leído que eso fuera posible dado que una respuesta tiene relación directa con la pregunta, pero ¿por qué no simplemente copiar el contenido de la pregunta y responderla donde sea necesario? ¿No consideras que sería la forma más sencilla y rápida?

Comment: No se puede. Deberás copiar el contenido de tu respuesta eliminada y crear una nueva respuesta en la pregunta esperada.

Comment: Ya está reabierta.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Entonces la respuesta es que no se puede ¿no?. Saludos.